# Sharepoint survey permissions

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, survey

I created a survey in my sharepoint online site.

If I give contribute permissions the user can add responses but can also edit permissions and add questions to the survey. Also, with contribute permissions, even if I set the survey advanced permissions to "Read responses that were created by the user" instead of "Read all responses" the user can still see all responses, even the other user responses, he also can edit and delete those answers...

If i give read permissions the user can't respond to the survey...

What can I do? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that users "can also edit permissions and add questions to the survey", I believe in 2 scenarios:

- The user has more pemissions than required at list or web level, probably being part of one or more group that has, for example, Design or Full Control permissions
- Your "Contribute" permissions level was changed, and their permission was raised

So please just check the current users permissions and which groups they are members, just entering on survey settings> permissions for this survey> check permissions. Just check which groups the user is associated and be sure they have appropriated permissions.

Other important thing is to check if the role *Contribute* remains with the original permissions. Remember that it's a best practice **to not change** the original permissions levels, and you may check it on site settings > site permissions > permissions levels.

You may check more details and how the permissions levels are configured at the following link:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/understanding-permission-levels-in-sharepoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848

Just for your information: if the user has the right permissions and be a member of the expected groups with the Contribute permissions, it must not be able to change anything at list level, like questions or permissions.. Except if it's a site collection administrator or something like that ;)

Comment: Thanks, someone changed the contribute permissions at the parent site... I've created a new contribute with the standard permissions to apply in my subsite and left the parent site like it was. Thanks again